# Restrict WCF to accept call from specific remote clients

Tags: .net, wcf, security

We have an internal application(ASP.net) on one server and a WCF Service on another. How do i make sure that WCF Service can only accept calls from that application? I'm hoping there is a way for WCF to allow access using the AppPool Identity(domain service) off the calling application.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways of doing that, but all involve authenticating the incoming calls at the WCF side.

You could use client certificates and only issue a certificate to the ASP.NET application. This is a very common way to do machine to machine authentication.

If you're in a Windows Active Directory domain, you could use Kerberos authentication if your ASP.NET application is running under its own account.

Another alternative would be to use username-password authentication and store the credentials securely on the ASP.NET machine.

Take a look at this link for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx